# How can I install KDE 4 on Kubuntu Wily 15.10?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, kde4

I recently upgraded to Kubuntu 15.10 from 14.04 LTS, and have found that KDE/Plasma 5 has too many bugs and I would like to use KDE 4 again. But I want to keep the rest of Kubuntu 15.10 and all the updates/fixes it brings.

Is there a way for me to install KDE 4 on Kubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So far I don't know a way to "downgrade" the KDE Version of kubuntu 15.10 to KDE4.

Depending of what kind of problems you have you can try to upgrade to Plasma 5.4.3 and KDE Applications 15.08.3 with adding the ppa ppa:kubuntu-ppa/ppa see [kubuntu news](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-4-3-and-applications-15-08-3-for-kubuntu-15-10/)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/ppa
```

As an alternative you can give Linux Mint 17.3 KDE a try.

> Linux Mint 17.3 features KDE 4.14, MDM 2.0, a Linux kernel 3.19 and an Ubuntu 14.04 package base
>
> Kernel 4.2.0 is also available in the repositories. However please be cautious with it if you are using proprietary drivers.

Comment: I've already added the Kubuntu updates PPA, and I have the same issues. Linux Mint is also based on 14.04 which I want to avoid. From what I understand, KDE4  can be installed parallel to KDE/Plasma 5.